# Why is find not listing matching files when preceded by an asterisk(*)?

Tags: shell, find, quoting, wildcards

On `Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit`, I have set `/lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers` to be my current directory. I intend to search all files having `net` present as a sub-string. If I search with a regex of `*net*`, only the `./net` directory is returned as the search result. However, if I specify exact file name, then only it lists out the relevant file (Useless because not always I know the exact file name to cross check).

```
$ find . -name *net* 
./net
$ find . -name *usbnet* 
./net/usb/usbnet.ko
$ pwd
/lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers
```

What mistake am I making?

Comment: it's a matter of shell expansion see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375819/wildcards-and-double-quotes-with-find-name-command

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because when you use just `*net*` (without any quoting or escaping), it will be expanded by the shell as the (existing) `net` file/directory in the current directory before the `find` command run. So the command becomes:

```
find . -name net
```

As you can see it is just matching `net`, so `usbnet.ko` will not be matched.

Also note that, without quoting and escaping, if the pattern does not match (and `nullglob` and `failglob` options are disabled), it is treated *as is*. So for example, for `find . -name *net*`, if no file name contains `net` in current directory the pattern find gets is `*net*`.

---

So to solve the problem, you need to avoid the shell globbing, to do so you can use quoting or escaping the glob patterns:

```
find . -name '*net*' 
find . -name "*net*" 
find . -name \*net\*
```

Comment: What I didn't understand is why bash strips off wildcards(*) during expansion (if used without quoting or escaping).

Comment: It is not stripping them, it is using them to match.

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock `bash` does not strip off wildcards, do `ls *net*` and you will see you have only one file named `net` n that directory. If there are other files e.g. `foonetbar`, `spamnet`, then `*net*` would match them too..

Comment: A lot of users imagine that the globbing is done in `ls`. To see what the shell is doing, and break this illusion, do `echo *net*`.

Comment: and the other point is that when a pattern does *not* match, then bash does *not* remove any of the wildcard characters, and `find` gets the argument `*usbnet*` with asterisks

Comment: @glennjackman Missed that..edited..

Comment: What's the difference between `find . -name '*net*' ` and `find . -name *net* `?